# span inside button, is not clickable in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

**My CODE**

---

*HTML:*

```
<p id="console"></p>
<button>Click <span class="icon"></span>
</button>
```

*JS:*

```
$('.icon').click(function () {
    $('#console').html('Icon has been clicked');
    return false;
});

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#console').html('Button has been clicked');
});
```

*CSS:*

```
.icon {
    background-position: -96px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    line-height: 14px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background-image: url("http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/img/glyphicons-halflings.png"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/vFyp2/)

**Problem**

---

I am able to click on `.icon` in Chrome , but not in Firefox. When I click on `.icon`, it clicks on whole `button`.

**Question:**

---

Isnt my code valid ? If my code is valid, whats the solution to this problem.

**What I have tried**

---

1. I have tried doing `$('.icon').click()` from console and it works perfectly in ff, so I guess the problem is that `span` is not clickable inside `button`.
2. `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation` are not working either.
3. I've tried putting `&nbsp;` inside `span` but its not working either.

Comment: Are you able to click on `.icon` and `button` separately ? I am using firefbox 18.0.1 for ubuntu 12.04

Comment: button is clickable by default, you are not suposed to click on anything inside it, if this works on chrome, its not on purpose. Instead of button, use another tag like div, and style it(fake a button)

Comment: Even if it worked it would be a serious usability problem.

Comment: It seems to work for me in Chrome and FF. Remember that an event like this bubbles up the DOM tree.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it shouldn't bubble if the "icon" event handler returns `false` though (even though I think it shouldn't work anyway)

Comment: The solution is to not use `<button>`, and perhaps an anchor `<a>` instead.

Comment: e.stopPropagation does not work either

Comment: I can use `div` instead. But whats wrong here ? `span` is a valid child of `button`

Comment: @Jashwant it is valid html, but not supposed to do what you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Refer to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5), most notably the forbidden contents (in the SGML definition; for assistance reading that, [look here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3)): `a`s, `form`s, form "controls" (`input`, `select`, etc), and `fieldset`s.

While you are correct in asserting that `span`s (and `div`s, etc) are legal contents of a `button` element, the illegal elements are all to do with having button content that does anything other than layout / styling.

I don't see anything in the spec precluding what you're trying to do, but I do see a lot discouraging it, and would be unsurprised if various browsers also "discouraged" that by not supporting it.

Which is to say: find another way to do what you want if you want to have cross-browser support.  I don't understand what you're actually trying to do, so I don't think its possible to propose alternatives. I get that you want to respond differently to clicking on the button vs the icon -- but that's a (good, btw) demonstration of what you don't want to happen, not an explanation of an actual problem you want to solve.

One way might be to not use a button, and instead use another `span` or a `div`:

```
<p id="console"></p>
<div class="button_replace">Click <span class="icon"></span></div>
<script>
  $('.icon').click(function () {
    $('#console').html('Icon has been clicked');
    return false;
  });
  $('.button_replace').click(function () {
    $('#console').html('Button has been clicked');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you may need to use stopPropagation in addition to / instead of `return false;`, I haven't checked in jsFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

If you're here, maybe this solution will work for you, even though it's not really related directly to the question.

If you've applied a

- `$("button").click()` listener, and
- your button contains a `<span>` or any other `<tag>`, and
- your `.click` callback function refers to `$(this)` (or even `this`)

**Then, if you click on the button, `this` will likely be the top-most tag you CLICKED ON.**

This will often, such as in my case, misattribute the caller, causing script errors.

Hope it helps someone out there!

Answer (score 0):

Using previous answers, I found that just changing my  to  fixed the problem and allowed me to have content inside the button.
The styling is virtually the same, I just left the same bootstrap button classes and  element in there and it behaves just the same as before. The tabindex is there because I'm using a dropdown list inside the button so that the button (now div) can be focused and have (blur) or (focusout) event in Angular.