# Buttons not working at all (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm getting mad about this.Long story short :
This is the show-cart.php where cart is shown.

[image]

When i click Remove button , the event I call works 1 over 10 times about.Below it's the simple code.What's wrong? Why it's not working properly?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">
                            <span onclick="alert('smth')"; class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove""></span> Remove
                        </button>
```

This is my console [image]

Comment: Any error in the console?

Comment: P.S I have the same problem with other buttons , event is not called , or called after 10 clicks.

Comment: No @Hatef , nothing , I'm posting a screen.

Comment: class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove". make it correct also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `onclick` function on the `button` element instead of `span`.  The following snippet shows this along with some other cleanup in your code.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="alert('smth')">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Remove
</button>
```

Comment: Ok this is working. But why ? Is giving on click on span wrong?

Comment: There are a couple existing questions and answers which may help give some insight.  I think the short version is that you might be able to make it work but it is not intuitive and is discouraged in practice for that reason.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689879/span-inside-button-is-not-clickable-in-ff