# Weird hover behavior in IE 11 and Firefox

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a fairly simple hover effect on a span inside a button

HTML:

```
<span class="content">text</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.content:hover {
     background-color: #2b9385;
     background-image: linear-gradient(#2b9385, #007571);
    color: red;
}
```

When I hover over the span, it works fine in Edge and Chrome. In Firefox and IE 11, nothing happens.

Here is the weird part. If I use the dev. tools and inspect the element with hover checked, the CSS changes to the correct values and the background of the span changes correctly on the screen, it just doesn't work when I actually hover over it with the mouse. If I add "color:blue" to the hover section, the text color changes as it should when I hover over it, only the background part doesn't work.

I've tried adding vendor prefixes to the linear gradient part, but it didn't help (and shouldn't be needed in either case). Using #hex color values also didn't help.

Any clues appreciated.

I've added a Pen so you can see that it works in Chrome but not in FF. If you inspect the .content span in Firebug and click on the hover checkbox, the styles will be applied correctly, even though hovering over the button does nothing.

[Pen](https://codepen.io/BobRay/pen/jpawyK)

Comment: What are you expecting your invalid CSS to do?

Comment: Bad typing. I should have pasted it. Here's the actual code: 
    span.content:hover {
         background-color: #2b9385;
         background-image: linear-gradient(#2b9385, #007571);
        color: red;
    }

Comment: See the CodePen example I've added.

Comment: Your example does not show the error you present in your codepen. You must provide a  [mcve]

Comment: I am able to reproduce and it's strange ...

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689879/span-inside-button-is-not-clickable-in-ff?lq=1 .. I think you should avoid span inside button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this. It will definitely help.

```
.progress-button:hover span#button_content.content {
    background-color: #2b9385;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#2b9385, #007571);
    cursor: pointer;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted your answer. It is exactly what I needed (though it breaks things in IE 11).  

I also don't know why the question was downvoted once the Pen was up (a number of people have seen the problem when viewing the Pen). It's a difficult problem and the fix is not at all obvious.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing colon(:) so just try this

```
background-image:(red, orange);
```

Comment: I've update the code in the question and added a Pen. The problem persists.