# Link inside a button not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, button, hyperlink

I have two links inside a button but the links don't seem to work on Firefox.

```
<button class="btn login">
    <a href="/login"><b>Log In</b></a> 
          | 
<a href="/signup"><b>Sign Up</b></a>
</button>
```

I tried JavaScript onclick and redirecting - even that is not working.

Comment: No - you can't have "interactive" elements inside other ones.  It may work in some browsers sometimes, but it's wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nesting <a> inside <button> doesn't work in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280684/nesting-a-inside-button-doesnt-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This doesn't work because [it is not allowed by HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element):

> **Content model:** Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive
>   content descendant.

[Interactive content means any of the following elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/content-models.html#interactive-content):

> a audio (if the controls attribute is present) button details embed
>   iframe img (if the usemap attribute is present) input (if the type
>   attribute is not in the hidden state) keygen label menu (if the type
>   attribute is in the toolbar state) object (if the usemap attribute is
>   present) select textarea video (if the controls attribute is present)

If it does work in some browsers it's just because they're trying to
play nice with malformed markup and provide **some** sort of meaningful result.

In other words: rewrite your HTML, it's a mess. If you want the links to look like they're in a button, put them in a `div` element and style that to look like one, instead of abusing semantically wrong elements for it.

Comment: Perhaps elaborate by explaining when and why <button>s went from being alternatives to <input>s with type = button which supported images and text (and therefore links) inside to HTML 5 changing something that previously worked?

Comment: @deji that is incorrect - interactive content was never allowed. Text and images are not interactive.

Answer (score 12):

[`<a>` is not allowed inside `<button>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element)

> Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

`<a>` is interactive content (regardless of whether it has an `href` apparently, but yours do).  Thus you can't depend on having the links as children of the button and what Firefox is doing is correct.  Use another element to contain the `<a>`s

Answer (score 6):

> I have two links inside a button but […]

*“Yeah, but let me stop you right there …”*

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element:

> 4.10.8 The button element Content model: Phrasing content, but there must be no [interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant.
>
> --->
>
> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user interaction.
> ⇒ a, audio […]

So, if you are writing invalid HTML, expect unexpected behavior ;-)

Comment: +1: i would have ended that sentence with "expect the unexpected" :)

Answer (score 4):

You can add this in the button element.

onclick="window.location.href='/link1'"

Example

`<button onclick="window.location.href='/login'">Login</button>`

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid HTML,

Do something like this instead:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Log in</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use javascript: window.location for the button.

```
<div class="product">
<button onClick="javascript: window.location='/checkout/outfield-
banner/1'">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Or, you can put the button inside the anchor, it won't have the exact same look since it'll be two different buttons, but it will be a button that acts as a link.  It's still not technically correct but it **does** work in FireFox.

```
<a href="/login">
  <button class="btn login">
    <b>Log In</b>
  </button>
</a> 
<a href="/signup">
  <button class="btn login">
    <b>Sign Up</b>
  </button>
</a>
```