# asp LinkButton inside html Button tag

Tags: asp.net, button, postback, linkbutton

I have some Html code that contains the button tag "`<button></button>`".

I have noticed that if I place a linkbutton inside this element, the postback of the linkbutton will never occur.

So this is not working :

```
<button><asp:LinkButton ID="lnkExample" OnClick="lnkExampleBtn_Click"runat="server">Text</asp:LinkButton></button>
```

The server method "lnkExampleBtn_Click" will never be launched.

How come the postback doesn't work ?

Is there a way to have a linkbutton work inside the "button" tag ?

I also tried putting an href element with javascript _doPostback specific method, but that is not working either.

Comment: Why do you want a linkbutton in a button??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your case.

Here's code behind:

```
public partial class Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTest.Text = "Test";
    }

    protected void btnTest2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblTest.Text = "Test2";
    }
}
```

And here's aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="btnTest" runat="server" OnClick="btnTest_Click">Test</asp:LinkButton>
            <button><asp:LinkButton ID="btnTest2" runat="server" OnClick="btnTest2_Click">Test2</asp:LinkButton></button>
            <button><a href="http://www.google.com/">test</a></button>
            <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

What I found is - it depends on browser. In Chrome it's possible to place LinkButton inside  tags. In Firefox and IE 10 it's not.

The reason why it's not working is simple - **it's not allowed by the HTML 5 standard**. You just can't embed a link inside a button.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

[Link inside a button not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253410/link-inside-a-button-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations.