# How to invoke an action in struts on click of a button in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want my page to be redirected to some other page on button click, whose action is mapped in **`struts.xml`**

How to achieve this?

Comment: With what exactly are you having problems?

Comment: I need to somehow go to my action that is mapped in struts.xml on click of the back button. That action has other results mapped that will in turn redirect to the required jsp.

Comment: *on click of the back button* ? Browser back button?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A forum, not a code-writing service. Please post all the code you have written or tried so far and then specify your particular problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at below solution

```
<button><a htref="/someAction.action">Back</a></button>
```

So whenever you will press the button then action will call and then it does its work.

If link inside  button will not work you can try onclick event of jquery or javascript

I like to use jquery

So the code will look like.

```
<button id="backButtonClick">Back</button>

$("#backButtonClick").click(function(e){
   window.location.href="someAction.action";
});
```

Maybe this will help you.

Comment: Horrible, horrible way. See [Link inside a button not working in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17253410/1700321).

Comment: you have try it on firfox

Comment: ok i have edited the code i have added alternative solution by using javascript or you can try by adding button inside link i.e  <a htref="/someAction.action"><button>Back</button></a>

like that

Answer (score 1):

```
<button><a href="<s:url action='deleteStudent'/>">Delete</a></button>
```

This one will work if some one wants to avoid js