# Link, created by Tampermonkey, works in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I wrote a simple script to add a floating button to a series of pages that redirects to a URL depending on some features. This is added via Tampermonkey.

The following produces a button in both Chrome and Firefox but it is only clickable in Chrome:

```
var html = '<div id="gmSomeID"><button id="tapButton" type="submit"><a href="'+output_url+'" style="color:white">A</a></button></div>';
    $("body").append(html);
```

Any ideas what may be driving the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That code is semantically ambiguous and [**invalid HTML**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253410/link-inside-a-button-not-working-in-firefox); don't code that way!

Consider:

```js
var output_url = '#';
var newHtml = `
    <div>
        <button id="badButton" type="submit">
            <a id="badLink" href="${output_url}">Click me</a>
        </button>
    </div>
`;
$("body").prepend (newHtml);
$("#badButton, #badLink").click ( zEvent => {
    console.log ("Clicked: ", zEvent.target.id);
} );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What do you expect would happen?

- The button code tells the browser to execute any event handlers on the button and then submit the containing form. If there was such a form, submitting it would would normally navigate the page away from its current instance -- blocking the link from executing.
- The link code would navigate away, blocking the button from executing.

If you run that code and click, then *currently* you get:

- On Chromium based browsers: `Clicked:  badLink`.
- On Firefox: `Clicked:  badButton`.

Because it's invalid HTML, browsers are not guaranteed to handle it in a uniform way.

So:

1. **Do not put hyperlinks inside buttons.**
2. If you want the HTML **to navigate to another page, use a link, not a button.**  You can use CSS to make it *look* like button.
3. If you want the HTML **to change the state of the page** or to submit or reset a form, **use a button.**
4. Do not use `type="submit"` unless the button is inside a form and really meant to submit it.  Always specify `type="button"` by default, to avoid unexpected behavior.