# Links in my HTML file don't work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a HTML file with some links. These links are for other HTML files in my projects. These links are not working in Firefox but in Chrome and Edge they do.
How can I solve it?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: <button class = "navbtn" id="btn_home"><a href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home </a></button>

Comment: the head :        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253410/link-inside-a-button-not-working-in-firefox