# Element inside button does not fire click event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/dpsr4dkr/) fiddle works in Chrome, but not Firefox. Anyone know why?

Here is the markup:

```
<button>
    <span onclick="alert('yoo')">hey</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Can you just use `<button onclick="alert('yoo')"></button>`?  That should work in all browsers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [span inside button, is not clickable in ff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689879/span-inside-button-is-not-clickable-in-ff)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069410/click-event-for-element-nested-within-a-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by definition, see [4.10.8 The button element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

> **Content model:**
>       Phrasing content, but there must be ***no interactive*** content descendant.

Comment: So you're saying it's a bug that Chrome does fire the alert?

Comment: Apparently Chrome likes to deviate from the spec

Comment: looks that way since IE11 and Opera also do not fire the alert. (*and since the specs describe it so ;)*)