# File input field inside button doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'd like to have a styled file `input` field on my page and therefore put it inside a `button` which it completely covers and made it invisible by setting its opactiy to 0.

This approach works pretty well in the latest version of Chrome but Firefox (and IE) won't open the file dialog when clicking the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/ch8xxvez/3/

```
<button style="width: 100px; height: 100px; position: relative;">Upload button
    <input type="file" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0;"></input>
</button>
```

The same code works if I replace the `button` element with a `div` but I'd really like to know if there is a way to make this work with the `button` tag in the latest versions of IE (>= 10), FF, Chrome & Edge.

Comment: That this works at all is fairly surprising: it shouldn't, the HTML is wrong. Put it in a div or similar element, make the file input `opacity: 0;`, and style the div/similar element, that is the simplest way to do what you're trying to do. Don't put form input elements inside other form input elements, it doesn't make any logical sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [span inside button, is not clickable in ff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14689879/span-inside-button-is-not-clickable-in-ff)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Input elements are not allowed inside button elements in HTML.

Write valid HTML instead of depending on consistent error recovery.

Make the button and input sibling elements and then position them within a container (such as a div).

Comment: @PaulMel — Read the current standard again. That rule remains.

Answer (score 4):

try it

[https://jsfiddle.net/DeivissonSedrez/0z6mq5yk/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/DeivissonSedrez/0z6mq5yk/)

```
<div class="fakeButton">Upload button
        <input type="file" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0;"></input>
</div>
    <style>
        .fakeButton{
            width: 100px; 
            height: 100px; 
            position: relative; 
            border:1px solid #000; 
            border-radius:3px; 
            text-align:center; 
            font: 15px arial; 
            line-height:90px;
            box-shadow: inset 0 2px 3px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 -3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 3px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);
            background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #D8D8D8 130%);
            background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #D8D8D8 130%);
            background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #D8D8D8 130%);
            background-image: linear-gradient(#EEEEEE, #D8D8D8 130%);
        }
    </style>
```

I put the input inside a div and made a div look like a button with css

They worked in my tests on IE, FF and Chrome

I hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

According to [W3 specification of the BUTTON tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#edef-BUTTON), you cannot inset the following tags inside a `<button>` tag:

- A
- INPUT
- SELECT
- TEXTAREA
- LABEL
- BUTTON
- FIELDSET

However, all the other block and inline tags are allowed.

Comment: Where does the specification say that? I cannot find anything about it in the linked specification. It's a long text and I haven't  perused it.

Comment: @SámalRasmussen the syntax is a bit odd, but the link should take you to the correct point of the documentation that says `(%flow;)* -(A|%formctrl;|FORM|FIELDSET)`. This means you can insert %flow elements other (-) than A, FORM, FIELDSET and any %formctrl elements. You can further click on the % starting groups to find out what they mean.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I was unable to parse that syntax, but your explanation helped!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure that you can do this as the W3C spec says you can not have interactive content (i.e. clickable content) inside a button.

> Content model:
>       Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

This question at least in context is also a [possible duplicate of this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517121/element-inside-button-does-not-fire-click-event-in-firefox) of which the answer here is accredited.

Comment: more recent spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sec-forms.html#the-button-element says the same

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid to have an `<input>` inside a `<button>`. Consider putting it inside a `<label>` instead, or a `<span>` with a click handler and suitable CSS or use anchor tags.