# (click) only working in Chrome not working in others

Tags: angular, google-chrome, typescript, firefox, microsoft-edge

I've created an Angular web app,

link :- http://mohitkyadav.github.io/algos-ngular

Now when I browse this site in Chrome, everything works fine as expected but in other browsers like Edge and Firefox when I click the elements in side-nav on my app nothing happens, after adding some `console.log("hi")` I figured out the problem.

**see this line on github**

https://github.com/mohitkyadav/algos-ngular/blob/master/src/app/views/content.component.html#L7

an click event should be fired.

(**typescript**)

https://github.com/mohitkyadav/algos-ngular/blob/master/src/app/components/content.component.ts#L34

As written in this line the event should print in the console. It's working fine in Chrome and UC browser PC but not working in Firefox and Edge.

When I click any item from side-nav, the code logs it in console in chrome but in Firefox the console is empty, nothing happens.

Please help me. You can test it your self open https://mohitkyadav.github.io/algos-ngular/

and also open your Chrome console and Firefox console and click side-nav items, please give me your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems it has nothing to do with angular.

Look at button definition in [HTML5 standart](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element)

> Content model:
>       Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

```
<button>
  <div (click)="fetchCode()">
    Click me but i won't work in Firefox in IE
  </div>
</button>
```

Clicking at the children elements won't work because it is nested inside a button.

You can either move click event to button

```
<button (click)="fetchCode()">
  <div>
    This should work
  </div>
</button>
```

or use another tag instead of button

```
<div class="button" >
  <div (click)="fetchCode()">
    This also should work
  </div>
</div>
```

See also

- [Missing click event for <span> inside <button> element on firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402033/missing-click-event-for-span-inside-button-element-on-firefox)
- [Element inside button does not fire click event in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26517121/element-inside-button-does-not-fire-click-event-in-firefox)

Comment: It's so nice to hear from you, thanks for such detailed answer. I've repaired my app.